# Wait for document ready in ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, dom, es6-modules

With hoisting, ES6 modules are loaded before the document is ready.

For example,

```
// module.js
console.log('body', document.body);
export let a = 1;

// main.js
import {a} from 'module'
```

log `body null` in the console.

How to have ES6 modules that use DOM manipulation and required `document ready`?

I tried to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 1;
});

export {a};
```

in my module but babel returned me an `Unexpected token` error.

I also tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  export let a = 1;
});
```

and I had an `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level` error.

**Update:**

I have the same problem with

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  var a = 1;
}

export {a};
```

because `a` is not defined.

that is to say the variable to export are not available (see my update).

**Update:**

Here is my attempt based on @MaciejSikora code:

```
function Test() {

   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{
      this.width = $(window).width();
   });

};

//example object method
Test.prototype.getElement = function(el) {
   return this[el];

};


export { Test };
```

In another file I do

```
var test = new Test();
var width = test.getElement('width');
```

But `width` is undefined.

Answer (score 45):

**DOM has not changed in ES6, ES6 gives new features to JavaScript, that is all**. In pure js exists event for dom loaded ( it is document ready from jquery equivalent ):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

    //Your code here
});
```

**Modules working with DOM tree can have listener inside, or should be used after dom is ready**. I created example `DomManipulate` component to show what I mean:

```
var DomManipulate=function(selector){

   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",()=>{

      this.element=document.querySelector(selector);

      if (typeof this.callback === 'function')
      this.callback();

   });

};

//HERE WE HAVE CALLBACK WHEN OUR MODULE CAN BE USED
DomManipulate.prototype.onReady=function(callback){

    this.callback=callback;

};

DomManipulate.prototype.getElement=function(){
    //example object method

   return this.element;

};

DomManipulate.prototype.write=function(text){

   return this.element.innerText=text;

};


export { DomManipulate };
```

So it is better approach and we have encapsulated component.

**Usage example:**

```
var d=new DomManipulate("#test");
d.onReady(()=>{d.write("Test text");});
```

Modules should be DOM independent, creating modules which are exporting DOM elements directly are very wrong practice. So it can be done in two ways:

1. Modules should get selectors DOM object in attributes and should be called after DOM is ready. So Your module has no idea where is called, but it needs ready DOM structure. In this situation DOM ready callback is only in main file which is using modules and call them.
2. Modules can have some DOM ready listeners but also We need some information when module can be used ( this situation I showed in example  and onReady function).

Comment: I see the idea but I can't make it work for my case. The problem is that when I instantiate and call `getElement`, the DOM is not necessarily ready and `this.element` is empty. See new update of my question.

Comment: Check my change

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @hhh I changed example and added some more information. Read last two points. I added also in example callback when module is ready, problems that it was not working it was because You used id before DOM was ready, so we need some callback to be sure. This approach is proper use of modules with DOM manipulation, sending script to end of page is not any solution at all.

Comment: The problem is that I don't wait for the DOM to manipulate it but to `export` other variables and the `export` statement cannot be in the `onReady()` function. My module needs two things: 1- wait for the DOM to do some manipulation and 2- export variables and functions that result from these manipulations.

Answer (score 5):

There is another, shorter (old) `vanilla` js expression to wait until the `DOM` is loaded:

```
window.onload=function(){}
```

The same with the `ES6` **Fat Arrow** Function:

```
window.onload=()=>{}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't receiving more upvotes. Seems to do exactly the same as `$(document).ready`

Comment: @JulesColle `onload` waits for DOM+images, `DOMContentLoaded` waits for DOM only. That might or might not make a difference depending on your needs, but it's not an exact equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Try to place your `<script>` tag at the bottom of `<body/>`. By doing this, `document.body` will be available and it won't throw an error.

Comment: Better is to use event on DOM loaded. Our script can be in any place of html.

Comment: @MaciejSikora I agree but can't make it work. See my update.

Comment: @MaciejSikora If we use your approach, all the code should come inside the `DOMContentLoaded` callback which is not good.

Comment: @PraneshRavi it is not true

Comment: @PraneshRavi Actually this does work for `document.body` but not for other div like `$('#header').height()` that I need. Any suggestion?

Comment: @hhh No, it should work. Make sure that your script tag is the last node inside body.

Comment: @PraneshRavi The script tag is well the last node in body. I use JQM maybe it is related?

Comment: @hhh https://github.com/praneshr/petch/blob/master/index.html take this as an example. The script tag is at the end of the page. By doing this script will be interpreted at the last. So, all the DOM elements above the script tag will be available when you try to access them. Hope it help!